# Alguém pode me ajudar entender esse código!

Tags: python

Alguém pode me ajudar falando o que cada parte desse código faz!

```
 from collections import Counter
def jaccard_repeats(a, b):
    """Jaccard similarity measure between input iterables,
    allowing repeated elements"""
    _a = Counter(a)
    _b = Counter(b)
    c = (_a - _b) + (_b - _a)
    n = sum(c.values())
    return 1 - n/(len(a) + len(b) - n)

list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'cat']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']
list3 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']     

jaccard_repeats(list1, list3)      
>>> 0.25
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste de mesa, ve o que a função `Counter` faz na documentação e ir passo a passo o fluxo do código e ir anotando num papel pra não se perder. Vai inclusive ajudar no seu amadurecimento como desenvolvedor.

Answer (score -3):

Procure utilizar o método de **divide and conquer** porque ao quebrar o código fica mais fácil de entender.

por exemplo:

O que significa esse primeiro trecho:

**from collections import Counter**

Dai, você vai fazendo linha a linha para compreender, pode incluir quantos comentários forem preciso para ir aprendendo.

Melhor pra você ir debugando seu próprio código e ir entendendo o que está acontecendo do que alguém te falar o que está acontecendo.

Boa sorte nos estudos!

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/284748)

Comment: Você ajudou muito né?